# How to solve the equation $u_t = u_{xx} + e^{−t} \sin(4x)$ where $0 < x < π$, with the boundary conditions given by $u(0, t) = 0$, $u(π, t) = 3$?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How do I solve the equation $u_t = u_{xx} + e^{−t}\sin(4x)$ where $0 < x < π$, with the boundary conditions given by $u(0, t) = 0$, $u(π, t) = 3$, and initial condition given by $u(x, 0) = \sin(3x)$?

I know to use the method of eigenfunction expansion but get lost when I try to do it .

Comment: Can someone guide me in the right direction here please?

Comment: Hint: break things down bit by bit. Nonlinearity, initial conditions, etc. Use linearity of $\partial_t$

Comment: I've got everything figured out except for the last part, which leads me to this question : (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579151/how-do-i-solve-yt-e-t-16-yt/1579159?noredirect=1#comment3214384_1579159) 

And looking at the first answer, I can kind of see the logic behind it.  I think I've got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below, the solution in term of Fourier series. Sorry for the unusual presentation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually managed to figure it out after a while and my answer matches yours. Very easy to follow!